# Log4j printing to console every time

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have placed following log4j.properties file in src folder of my eclipse dynamic web project. But everytime logs are getting printed on console though I am writing code to print the logs in file only. If I am deleting log4j.properties file then also it is getting printed on console.Don't know what went wrong.

```
###############################################################################

log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

###############################################################################

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=D:/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/LogFile.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p %c - %m%n

###############################################################################
```

I am using following code to print the logs.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
log.info("First log");
```

Comment: Post some of the lines which where printed to the console, please.

Comment: This is the way output is getting generated on console.        [INFO][com.sun.security.ntlm.Client] - First log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to override the log4j configuration in your class like this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;;

static{
     PropertyConfigurator.configure("src/main/resources/log4j.properties");
}
```

This assumes you have a file called `log4j.properties` under `src/main/resources`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nikhil

I have used follwing code by looking your code and it worked fine.

```
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;

PropertyConfigurator.configure(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties"));
```